# MySQL Cluster - Composite foreign key error: Missing index for constraint

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster

I want to add composite foreign key to my MySQL Cluster table. When I try locally the statement is executed, but on cluster I get the following error:

```
Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint... in the referenced table 'y'
```

This is the statement:

```
ALTER TABLE x
 ADD CONSTRAINT fk_x_y
 FOREIGN KEY (y_id, tenant_id) 
 REFERENCES y(id, tenant_id);
```

I have executed `SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM` for both tables and both columns in each table are the same. Also I have index in `y` table on `id, tenant_id`.
MySQL Cluster version: 8.0.25-cluster

Edit 1:

`SHOW CREATE TABLE` results:

Table `x`:

```
CREATE TABLE `x` (
   `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `tenant_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `fk_y_id_tenant_id` (`tenant_id`),
   CONSTRAINT `fk_x_tenant_id` FOREIGN KEY (`tenant_id`) REFERENCES `tenant` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
 ) ENGINE=ndbcluster AUTO_INCREMENT=446 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Table `y`:

```
CREATE TABLE `reference_list` (
   `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `tenant_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `y_id_tenant_id` (`id`,`tenant_id`),
   KEY `fk_y_id_tenant_id` (`tenant_id`),
   CONSTRAINT `fk_y_id_tenant_id` FOREIGN KEY (`tenant_id`) REFERENCES `tenant` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
 ) ENGINE=ndbcluster AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I am aware that tenant_id is `DEFAULT NULL` in one table and `NOT_NULL` in other, but changing both to `DEFAULT NULL` didn't solve the problem.

Comment: MySQL says you don't have an index on `(id, tenant_id)`, and although you say you have such an index, when in doubt, MySQL is usually right. Please add the table definitions (e.g. the output of `show create table y` (and x).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running: `SHOW WARNINGS;` I found out I had to add `UNIQUE` index on `id`, `tenant_id` columns.